# Table row that extends the entire width of table

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to have a `tr` extend the entire width of a table with multiple columns?

I want to have one row with multiple `td`s followed by another row with a single `td` that fills the width of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this tr add one td tag and give him the attribute colspan="**"

** are the number of cells that he need to capture.

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">big 1</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```